# Delete user on ArcGIS server against Oracle backend

Tags: arcgis-server, oracle-dbms

I have a problem, when we delete users, using the following command:

```
drop user sdedata cascade;
```

We get the this error:

> ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive sql level 1
>   ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete oracle

Comment: This is possibly caused by triggers, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901645/oracle-11g-ora-00604-error-occurred-at-recursive-sql-level-1

Comment: Once tables have been registered with ArcSDE or ArcGIS geodatabase, using DROP TABLE will corrupt ArcGIS metadata.  Dropping the SDE user while tables have SDE.ST_GEOMETRY columns will corrupt the referential integrity of your Oracle instance.